# how can i handle selected imageview in view by touch

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone.What i did is displaying the 4 imageview and animating them,means imageviews are moving randomly in view.Now how can i handle the particular selected imageview.when ever i select the an imageview among the four imageviews  the selected imageview  animation will stop and i need to get notification of which imageview is selected.how can i done this pls post some code or link.thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different ways and it depends on how you are currently moving the UIImageView.

1°) If UIImageView are not subclassed, who could check in the upper UIView when one is touched. To do this, use touchesBegan and touchesMoved function.

```
UITouch *touch = [ touches anyObject ];
CGPoint location = [ touch locationInView:view ];
```

With the location you can find if it's touching one of your 4 UIImageView and then doing what you want

2°) The other way, little more difficult but the one I prefer. You subclass UIImageView, animate them in this class, and when you get a touch Event stop the animation and do the same things that in 1°). By the way you may need to create a delegate to call function in others classes or use some Notifications

Good Luck !
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

Make them UIButtons and use: `[button setImage:forState:]` then you can use targets and actions.

Answer (score 0):

take look at touchesBegan,touchesMoved functions